# Automorphism $f$ so that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ for half the members of the group: is it an involution?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group.

Let $f: G \to G$ an automorphism such that at least half the elements of the group are sent to their inverses, i.e $$\mathrm{card}(\{g \in G|f(g) = g^{-1}\}) \geq \frac{\mathrm{card}(G)}{2}.$$
**Question** : Is $f$ an involution ?

(I know that people consider which the identity is not an involution, but for me an involution is only a function $h$ such that $h\circ h = \mathrm{id}$).

Thanks.

Comment: Some precisions : if $G$ is abelian and $card(G)$ is odd, $f$ is an involution, since $H = \{g \in G \mid f(g) = g^{-1}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, $card(G)$ is odd and $card(H) \geq card(G)/2$ $\Leftarrow$ $H=G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yes.

Let $X$ be the set of elements of $G$ inverted by $f$, and $H$ be the subgroup generated by $X$.

An element $h$ of $H$ is a product of elements inverted by $f$, so $H$ is invariant under the action of $f$   (that is $f(H)=H$), and if we apply $f$ two times on $h$ we obtain $h$. This amounts to saying that $f$ induces an involution on $H$.

If $H=G$ we are done.  If $H <G$, then $1 < |G:H| \leq |G|/|X| \leq 2$, it follows that $|G:H|= |G|/|X|=2$, so that  $H=X$ (since $H$ contains $X$).  This shows that $H$ is normal, and as it is invariant under $f$, $f$ induces an automorphism on the cyclic group of order 2, $G/H$. It follows that $f$ is the identity on $G/H$, so if $y \in G-H$, then $f(y)=yh$ for some element $h\in H=X$.  We have
$$f^2(y)=f(yh)=f(y)h^{-1}=yhh^{-1}=y.$$ 
Now any element of $G$ which does not lie in $H$ has the form $yx$ for some $x \in H$.  It follows that $f^2(yx)=f^2(y)f^2(x)=yx$.  If we take an element $x$ of $H=X$, then clearly $f^2(x)=x$.  Thus $f$ is an involution.