# If an automorphism sends more than half of the elements to themselves then it's the identity

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $f$ is an automorphism which sends more than half of the elements in $G$ to back to them, meaning $f(a)=a$. Conclude that $f$ is the identity.

I know it's something with symmetry but I failed to understand how to prove it formally.

Thanks!

Comment: HInt. What is the index of the subgroup of $G$  generated by the set of elements sent to themselves?

Comment: An automorphism maps generators to generators. And in a finite group, the smallest possible nontrivial subgroup H will have order of 2 or greater.

Comment: well the index is supposed to be 1. looking at it for g in G and h in H where H is the subgroup in question so f(gh)=f(g)f(h)=f(g)h. but how do I go from here?

Comment: Related : [Automorphism $f$ so that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ for half the members of the group: is it an involution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907512).

Comment: See also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234497/if-an-automorphism-sends-more-than-half-of-the-elements-to-themselfs-then-its-t).

Answer (score 8):

The set of all elements fixed by the automorphism is subgroup of $G$. If the order of this subgroup is more than half the size of $G$, then its order cannot divide the order of $G$ unless it is $G$ itself.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I think this only shows that the map is surjective (which is trivially true for automorphisms anyway), not that it is the identity.

Comment: By definition, the image of an automorphism is always the whole of $G$. You probably mean the fix-subgroup of the automorphism.

Comment: @ahulpke yes, I meant that the set of elements fixed by the automorphism is a subgroup. See my recent edit.

Comment: Could someone give an example of a group and non-identity automorphism, such that it is identity on exactly half of the elements of the group?

Comment: @fasdgr what does half mean for an infinite group?

Comment: sorry it needn't be infinite

Comment: This should probably be a separate question, but hint: consider a group with 4 elements.